# Как обновить проект в гитхабе

Tags: git, github

Создал репозиторий на гитхабе, ручками скопировал туда файлы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновил файлы. Пытаюсь обновить репозиторий, захожу в папку с проектом, делаю:

```
git init 
git add * 
git push site master
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
To https://github.com/dextroza11/dextroza11.github.io.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: не удалось отправить некоторые ссылки в «https://github.com/dextroza11/dextroza11.github.io.git»
подсказка: Обновления были отклонены, так как внешний репозиторий содержит
подсказка: изменения, которых у вас нет в вашем локальном репозитории.
подсказка: Обычно, это связанно с тем, что кто-то уже отправил изменения в 
подсказка: то же место. Перед повторной отправкой ваших изменений, вам нужно
подсказка: забрать и слить изменения из внешнего репозитория себе
подсказка: (например, с помощью «git pull …»).
подсказка: Для дополнительной информации, смотрите «Note about fast-forwards»
подсказка: в «git push --help».
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: так вам же черным по белому написано человеческим языком, в чем причина и что делать

Comment: были там какие-то изменения ранее, возможно с другой машины, `git pull` и всё дальше по накатанной. Если предыдущее не твое и не нужно, `git fetch`

Comment: Git init создаёт новый репозиторий. Вам нужно сделать git clone репозитория с гитхаба, в новую папку, и дальше работать в ней. Или работать в той папке, из которой вы изначально залили первую версию

Answer (score -1):

`git pull` выполните. Если случились конфликты - разрешите и потом уже `git push`.

Вообще с git работать очень удобно. Он многое пишет сразу в консоль если что идёт не так. И в принципе много комманд запоминать не надо. Вот, например, что обычно делается при реализации очередного таска

```
git pull
git checkout -b task_branch
...
git add path/to/file0
git rm path/to/file1
git mv path/to/file2 path/to/file3
...
git commit -am 'Changes'
git pull
git push
git checkout master
git merge task_branch
git push
```